# How to return object from a function in my case?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am facing an weird issue in my code. 
I need to pass an object to a function and assign the return object.

In my code.

```
$scope.items.filter(function(item) {
    item = getName(item)
    console.log(item)  -> I can see item.name exist.
})

var getName = function(item) {
    var id = item.id;
    switch (id){
       case 1:
           item.name = 'new'; 
           return item;
       break;
       case 2:
           item.name = 'used';        
           return item;
       break;
       case 3:
           item.name='junk';
           return item;
       break;
       default:
    }
}
```

html

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{item.name}}   ------> doesn't show anything....
</div>
```

I am not sure why it doesn't show any value in html. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mdgvau9m/1/ - looks fine

Comment: You are not doing any filtering of the array... just iteration of it so use `.forEach()` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mdgvau9m/1/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried assigning your $scope inside the getname function?

```js
var getName = function(item) {
    var id = item.id;
    switch (id){
       case 1:
           $scope.item.name = 'new'; 
           break;
       break;
       case 2:
           $scope.item.name = 'used';        
           break;
       break;
       case 3:
           $scope.item.name='junk';
           break;
       break;
       default:
    }
}
```

I cant test this at the moment but let me know how you get on.